# Custom button border style does not change on IsPressed event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, triggers

I'm trying to recreate a Valve VGUI interface style in WPF. So far I am able to assign a border to a button, but the border style does not change when pressing the button.

Here's my XAML code:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BorderLight_Style" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#889180" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,0,0" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BorderShadow_Style" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282E22" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BorderLight_Style_pressed" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282E22" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,0,0" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BorderShadow_Style_pressed" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#889180" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4C5844" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4C5844" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#D8DED3" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Style="{StaticResource BorderShadow_Style}">
                        <Border x:Name="border2" Style="{StaticResource BorderLight_Style}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource BorderShadow_Style_pressed}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border2" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource BorderLight_Style_pressed}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Am I doing anything wrong with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls need to have a defined `Background` property to participate in hit-testing - and thus to allow the `IsPressed` property to be set on a `Button` for example.

Set the `Background` property of your inner `Border` to any valid value - such as `Transparent` - to fix your `Trigger`.

---

**Note:** if you were to press `TAB` to select your button and press the space bar, you would see your `Trigger` working even though you didn't set it any background, because `IsPressed` [also reacts to the space bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).